# return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key) 3622 except KeyError as err

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4',
                           'col5', 'col6'])
vec = [a,b,c,d,...]
for v in vec:
    name = 'name'      
    df.loc[name]['col1'] = v
  ....
```

And I got error that:
[image]

How to solve such error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, using df.at[name] = v